# Выдача прав группе пользователей

Tags: laravel

Имеется блог. В нем есть посты. Когда админ или пользователь добавляет пост он может выбрать кому он будет доступен для подробного просмотра. Пост должен быть доступен для просмотра именно той группе пользователей которую укажут для остальных будет отказано в доступе. Пробую использовать Шлюзы (Gate), не могу справиться. На толкните на мысль для решения этой задачи.